# LEFT JOIN on SELECT AS alias causing column not found on WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search user by 'user_location' which is an alias of location.detail
And I made this following query :

```
SELECT user.*, location.detail as user_location 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN location
ON user.id = location.user_id
WHERE user_location = 'jakarta';
```

It's resulting error says,

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_location' in 'where clause'
```

Why is it? what is the solution?
Any answer will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't user an alias in the where in the same query you created it. So you should do:

```
SELECT user.*, location.detail as user_location 
  FROM user 
        LEFT JOIN location
          ON user.id = location.user_id
 WHERE location.detail = 'jakarta';
```

If you still want to use that column you have to wrap it in a subquery:

```
select * from
(
SELECT user.*, location.detail as user_location 
  FROM user 
        LEFT JOIN location
          ON user.id = location.user_id
) a
where user_location = 'jakarta';
```

As @spencer7593 mentioned you can use an alias in the same query in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Another (less desirable in terms of performance) alternative: the column alias `user_location` could be referenced in a `HAVING` clause. `HAVING user_location = 'jakarta'`.

Comment: @spencer7593 yes you are right :) I did not added it because it was a use in where section. I will edit with this information :) thanks.

Comment: @JorgeCampos . . . MySQL materializes the subquery, so that is not a recommended solution.

Comment: Good to know that @GordonLinoff I will keep in mind for the next answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious and correct solution is to repeat the expression in the `WHERE` clause.  Sometimes, the expressions are more complicated (think distance calculations).  MySQL has an extension to SQL that allows you to use `HAVING` for this purpose:

```
SELECT u.*, l.detail as user_location 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     location l
     ON u.id = l.user_id
HAVING user_location = 'jakarta';
```

I don't actually recommend it for this particular query (after all, "user_location" is longer to type out than "l.detail").  Under some circumstances, though, this can be convenient.

More important than these considerations is that your query is really an `INNER JOIN`.  You should specify it as such:

```
SELECT u.*, l.detail as user_location 
FROM user u INNER JOIN
     location l
     ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE l.detail = 'jakarta';
```

The filtering condition filters out all unmatched rows.  Using a `LEFT JOIN` inappropriately confuses people and might confuse the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aliases in Where clause in mysql. Try

```
SELECT user.*, location.detail as user_location 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN location
ON user.id = location.user_id
WHERE location.detail = 'jakarta';
```